# Protobuf-Net ArgumentNullException

Tags: protobuf-net

Im trying to use protobuf-net to send a class (called RPCMessage), which includes a list of another custom class (called MessageArguments). Ive extended MessageArguments to have a different class based on what value type I wish the argument to be (in this case a float). I am getting the follwing exception: ArgumentNullException: Known type cannot be blank. I am using .Net 3.5 if that helps.

Code to serialise:

```
public static void EncodeMessage(MessageType messageType, object messageClass, ref NetOutgoingMessage outMessage){
    byte[] serialised;

    var serializableObject = messageClass as RPCMessage;
    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
    Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(memStream, serializableObject,
    PrefixStyle.Base128);       
}
```

Code to store message:

```
[Serializable,
ProtoContract,
ProtoInclude(3, typeof(FloatArgument))]
public class RPCMessage {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public byte code;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public List<MessageArgument> args;

    public RPCMessage(){}

    public RPCMessage (byte _code, List<MessageArgument> _args){
        code = _code;
        args = _args;
    }
}
```

The code to store the message arguments:

```
[Serializable,
ProtoContract,
ProtoInclude(3, typeof(FloatArgument)))]
public class MessageArgument{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public byte id; 

    public MessageArgument(){}

    public MessageArgument(byte _id){
        id = _id;
    }
}
```

And finally, is called by

```
List<MessageArgument> args = new List<MessageArgument>();
args.Add(new FloatArgument(0, 1f));
MessageParser.EncodeMessage(type, new RPCMessage(0, args), ref outMessage);
```

I know I'm probably missing something basic, but I cant for the life of me work out what that is

Comment: any chance of a stacktrace from the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough to repro fully, but some observations:

- `[ProtoInclude]` represents inheritance hierarchy; it is impossible that `FloatArgument` is derived from both `MessageArgument` and `RPCMessage`, so I will assume (by naming) that the inclusion on `RPCMessage` is incorrect and should be removed
- since you are using `object`, you can't use the generic API; try instead:

  ```
  Serializer.NonGeneric.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(memStream,
       serializableObject, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
  ```

this then serializes and clones successfully.